# Scroll UITableView when editing TextField

Tags: ios, swift

How I can scroll table view to position TextField to center of the screen when keyboard has shown?

Comment: There are answers in Swift in the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to subscribe on `NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow` and scroll the table when it needed.

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .middle, animated: true)
```